# RxJS - Control multiple parallel executions

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a scenario where I have to control multiple PTZ cameras to take photos of multiple angles each. Therefore, for example:
`Camera A` will take angles `A1`, `A2`, `A3`
`Camera B` will take angles `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, `B4`

Moving the camera to point to the correct angle, capturing the image and uploading the image, are async functions that return promises.
`moveCamera( angle )`
`captureImage()`
`uploadImage()`

The cameras have to operate in parallel, but the angles taken by each camera have to be done in sequence.

I somehow feel that this can be solved by RxJS easily, but I'm struggling to piece them together. The best that I could, is something like the solution below which somehow made the cameras process in sequence to each other. Note that I use `redux-observable`, code below is the best I could in *plain* RxJS. Please pardon my RxJS.

```js
const angles = {
  'Camera A': [ 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' ],
  'Camera B': [ 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4' ],
}
const cameras = of( [ 'Camera A', 'Camera B' ] );
const cameraRun = cameras.pipe(
  mergeMap( camera => {
    // in redux-observable, I could return an array here
    return of( angles[ camera ] );
  } )
);
cameraRun.pipe(
  concatMap( angle => {
    return moveCamera( angle )
      .then( () => captureImage() )
      .then( () => uploadImage() )
      .then( () => console.log( 'Image success' ) );
  } )
)
```

For those who know `redux-observable`, I have 3 epics:
`RUN_CAMERA_SET_ROUTINE` - runs all the cameras inside a `mergeMap`
`RUN_CAMERA_ROUTINE` - runs all angles for each camera inside a `mergeMap`
`CAPTURE_IMAGE` - runs the async functions above inside one `concatMap`

My initial thought was `CAPTURE_IMAGE` will be "grouped" due to `mergeMap` spawning streams, but I was wrong. It seems `CAPTURE_IMAGE` is still one stream queuing every angle for all cameras.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot at this.  I put up a solution in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-55069868?file=index.ts) to show my thinking.  Click on the console before clicking on the button to start a new run.

Some points about this solution:

- I only use `start$` to kick off a new run with a click of the mouse, it is not important to the solution.
- I mocked the three camera promise functions with various timeouts just to show how things are executed in sequence, but how both cameras go in parallel.
- I also pass in a variable for `camera` to each camera function, but this is only so the console.log() can show what camera is doing what clearly.
- I did not do anything with `redux-observable`, but rather kept it vanilla `rxjs`.
- I converted the taking of a Photo into an observable sequence with `concat()` rather than leaving it as you had it with a chain of promises - this isn't necessary, just a different way to approach it.
- I left the cameras as separate Observables (`cameraA$` and `cameraB$`), but this could also be done with an array of cameras.

Feel free to fork this and change it to be closer to what you are looking for.

Here is what is in the StackBlitz:

```
import { mergeMap, concatMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { fromEvent, from, concat, merge, defer } from 'rxjs';

const moveCamera = (camera, angle) => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`moved: ${camera} angle: ${angle}`);
      resolve();
    }, 1000) }
);

const captureImage = (camera) => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${camera} captured image.`);
      resolve();
    }, 100) }
);

const uploadImage = (camera) => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${camera} uploaded image.`);
      resolve();
    }, 2000) }
);


const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');

const takeAPhoto$ = (camera, angle) => concat(
  defer(() => moveCamera(camera, angle)),
  defer(() => captureImage(camera)),
  defer(() => uploadImage(camera))
);

const cameraA$ = from(['A1', 'A2', 'A3']).pipe(
  concatMap(angle => takeAPhoto$('Camera A', angle))
);

const cameraB$ = from(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']).pipe(
  concatMap(angle => takeAPhoto$('Camera B', angle))
);

start$.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('\n\nstart new run')),
  mergeMap(() => merge(cameraA$, cameraB$)),
).subscribe();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Similar answer to @fridoo. Chosen answer due to clarity on how the verbosity of the code explains the idea.

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look at this, i don't know why this isn't working. I want to add cameras dynamically.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-55069868-wnjpol

Answer (score 4):

Your question comes down to executing some Observables in parallel others in sequence and creating Observables from Promises.

1. To execute multiple Observables in parallel either use:

- [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin), if you only want the final Observable to emit once all camera actions completed
- [`merge`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge), if you want the final Observable to emit every time a single camera action succeeds

2. Use [`concat`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) to execute multiple Observables in sequence.
3. Use [`defer`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/defer) to create an Observable from a Promise but don't execute the Promise immediately.

You then have to

- construct an array of Observables that you want to execute in sequence.
  (the actions for each angle of a single camera)
- construct an array of Observables that you want to execute in parallel.
  (the camera actions for each camera).

This could be the code in plain RxJS

```js
import { concat, forkJoin, merge, defer } from 'rxjs';

const cameras = ['Camera A', 'Camera B'];
const cameraAngles = { 
  'Camera A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 
  'Camera B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'] 
}

// Performs a camera action consisting of multiple parts. Returns a Promise.
// camera: e.g. 'Camera A', angle: e.g. 'A1'
const doCameraAction = (camera, angle) => moveCamera(angle)
  .then(() => captureImage())
  .then(() => uploadImage())
  .then(() => console.log('Image success'));

// Creates an Observables that executes multiple camera actions in sequence.
// camera: e.g. 'Camera A', angles: e.g. ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
const getCameraActionSequence$ = (camera, angles) => concat(
  // the array of Observables we want to execute in sequence
  ...angles.map(angle => defer(() => doCameraAction(camera, angle)))
);

// An Observable that will execute multiple camera action sequences in in parallel
const multiCameraActions$ = forkJoin(
  // the array of Observables we want to execute in parallel
  cameras.map(camera => getCameraActionSequence$(camera, cameraAngles[camera]))
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gj1dny?file=index.ts

Comment: Really good mention of `forkJoin` and concise code. If I could accept two answers, I would accept this answer as well. I now understand that you can dynamically queue `defer` in an array for later concatenation.